# Yii Ajax returns whole webpage in LimeSurvey Plug-in environment. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, limesurvey

In the Plug-in environment of LimeSurvey I have the following code snipped in a **view file** which will print out two **dependent dropdown lists**:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('survey_id', '', CHtml::listData(Survey::model()->active()->findAll(), 'sid', function($survey){return $survey->getLocalizedTitle()." ($survey->sid)";}), array(
        'ajax' => array(
        'type' => 'POST', //request type
        'cache' => false,
        'url' => 'direct?plugin=AcornReporting&function=MaturityLevels&action=dynamicResponses', //url to call.
        'update' => '#AcornMaturityLevels_response_id', //selector to update
        //'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
        //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
    )));

    //empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('response_id','', array(), array('style'=>'margin-left: 20px')); ?>
```

In the corresponding **controller** the following code should handle the ajax request:

```
public function actionDynamicResponses() {
    $data = CHtml::listData(Response::model($_POST['survey_id'])->findAll(), 'id', 'id');

    foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
    }
}
```

The Response **as seen in chromes dev tool** surprised me. **The first line is what I expected**. But what follows is a whole webpage whicht I do not know where it comes from.

```html
<option value="1">1</option><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/acorn/acorn-htmstyles/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/acorn/acorn-htmstyles/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/qTip2/dist/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-superfish/css/superfish.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-notify/ui.notify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/css/bootstrap-yii.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/7666aa2b/acorn.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/printablestyle.css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/adminstyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/adminstyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles-public/jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles-public/jquery.multiselect.filter.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/displayParticipants.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/7165e62e/css/notify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/b27bf437/nav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/css/select2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/qTip2/dist/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-superfish/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-superfish/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/third_party/jquery-notify/src/jquery.notify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/js/bootstrap.bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/scripts/admin/admin_core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/13abf2bc/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/b27bf437/nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
LS.data = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/acorn\/acorn-htm","showScriptName":true,"urlFormat":"path","adminImageUrl":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/styles\/gringegreen\/images\/","csrfToken":"e5329206519e6671e4962fac47a933a29149dfb0","replacementFields":{"path":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php\/admin\/limereplacementfields\/sa\/index"}};
$.ajaxSetup({data: {YII_CSRF_TOKEN: LS.data.csrfToken}});
LSdebug = {"session":{"adminlang":"en","LSWebUser":{"__returnUrl":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php\/plugins\/","__id":"1","__name":"admin","__states":{},"plugin":"Authdb"},"loginID":1,"user":"admin","full_name":"Administrator","htmleditormode":"default","templateeditormode":"default","questionselectormode":"default","dateformat":"1","session_hash":"697c7382a18ddfd48d3ac4bd1d6f5dc70df1ba2c4a86a2dffb8145896438ee95","USER_RIGHT_INITIALSUPERADMIN":1,"just_logged_in":true,"loginsummary":"<br \/>Welcome Administrator!<br \/>&nbsp;"},"server":{"HTTP_HOST":"localhost","HTTP_CONNECTION":"keep-alive","CONTENT_LENGTH":"231","HTTP_ACCEPT":"*\/*","HTTP_ORIGIN":"http:\/\/localhost","HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH":"XMLHttpRequest","HTTP_USER_AGENT":"Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/44.0.2403.155 Safari\/537.36","CONTENT_TYPE":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8","HTTP_REFERER":"http:\/\/localhost\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php\/plugins\/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&function=MaturityLevels&action=create","HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING":"gzip, deflate","HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE":"de-CH,de;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2","HTTP_COOKIE":"YII_CSRF_TOKEN=e5329206519e6671e4962fac47a933a29149dfb0; PHPSESSID=8sc7m2t2df348epd8his1c9vn7","HTTP_DNT":"1","PATH":"\/usr\/local\/sbin:\/usr\/local\/bin:\/usr\/sbin:\/usr\/bin:\/sbin:\/bin","SERVER_SIGNATURE":"<address>Apache\/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80<\/address>\n","SERVER_SOFTWARE":"Apache\/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)","SERVER_NAME":"localhost","SERVER_ADDR":"127.0.0.1","SERVER_PORT":"80","REMOTE_ADDR":"127.0.0.1","DOCUMENT_ROOT":"\/var\/www\/html","REQUEST_SCHEME":"http","CONTEXT_PREFIX":"","CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT":"\/var\/www\/html","SERVER_ADMIN":"webmaster@localhost","SCRIPT_FILENAME":"\/var\/www\/html\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php","REMOTE_PORT":"33729","GATEWAY_INTERFACE":"CGI\/1.1","SERVER_PROTOCOL":"HTTP\/1.1","REQUEST_METHOD":"POST","QUERY_STRING":"plugin=AcornReporting&function=MaturityLevels&action=dynamicResponses","REQUEST_URI":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php\/plugins\/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&function=MaturityLevels&action=dynamicResponses","SCRIPT_NAME":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php","PATH_INFO":"\/plugins\/direct","PATH_TRANSLATED":"\/var\/www\/html\/plugins\/direct","PHP_SELF":"\/acorn\/acorn-htm\/index.php\/plugins\/direct","REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT":1439512250.393,"REQUEST_TIME":1439512250}};
console.dir(LSdebug)

LS.messages=[];
/*]]>*/
</script>
<title>Limesurvey Administration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div id="notify-container" style="display:none;">
    <div id="default-notify"  class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
        <p>
            <a class="ui-notify-close" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:right">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <span style="float:left; margin:2px 5px 0 0;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-info">&nbsp;</span>
            #{message}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="error-notify"  class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-state-error error">
        <p> 
            <a class="ui-notify-close" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:right">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <span style="float:left; margin:2px 5px 0 0;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert">&nbsp;</span>
             #{message}
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- ui-state-success doesn't exist -->
    <div id="success-notify"  class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-state-success success">
        <p>
            <a class="ui-notify-close" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:right">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <span style="float:left; margin:2px 5px 0 0;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert">&nbsp;</span>
             #{message}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="maintitle titlebar">Acorn Human and Talent Management</div>            <div class="menubar">
    <div class="menubar-title ui-widget-header"><div class="menubar-title-left"><strong>Administration</strong> -- Logged in as:<strong><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/user?sa=personalsettings"> admin <img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/profile_edit.png" alt="Edit your personal preferences" /></a></strong></div></div><nav class="menubar"><ol class="menubar-left level0"><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/survey"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/home.png" alt="Default administration page" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/user"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/security.png" alt="Manage survey administrators" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/usergroups?sa=index"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/usergroup.png" alt="Create/edit user groups" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/globalsettings"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/global.png" alt="Global settings" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/checkintegrity"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/checkdb.png" alt="Check data integrity" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/dumpdb"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/backup.png" alt="Backup entire database" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/labels?sa=view"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/labels.png" alt="Edit label sets" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/templates"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/templates.png" alt="Template editor" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/participants"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/cpdb.png" alt="Central participant database/panel" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/plugin.png" alt="Plugin manager" /></a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Cockpit"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/bounce.png" alt="Acorn Reporting" /></a></li></ol><ol class="menubar-right level0"><li><label for="surveyid">Surveys:</label><select class="select" id="surveyid" data-route="admin/survey/sa/view" name="surveyid">
<option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Expired">
<option value="142833">(Demo) 3 Groups, some questions</option>
<option value="91">Acorn TM Survey with 2 Ems</option>
<option value="957916">ATM Survey active</option>
<option value="296591">ATM Survey finished</option>
<option value="92">ATM Survey, EM test</option>
<option value="134138">Deutsche Börse AG, V0.1</option>
<option value="678544">Short survey for testing EM class</option>
<option value="116811">V0.1 Test</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Inactive">
<option value="957791">Acorn HTM V0.1</option>
<option value="944555">Acorn Talent Management Survey</option>
<option value="356369">All groups, some questions</option>
<option value="543114">Copy1 of ATMS</option>
<option value="14272">Test of EM question attributes</option>
<option value="532311">v1.0 All Questions</option>
<option value="912161">V2.0 All Questions für Testing</option>
</optgroup>
</select></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/survey?sa=index"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/surveylist.png" alt="Detailed list of surveys" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/survey?sa=newsurvey"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/add.png" alt="Create, import, or copy a survey" /></a></li><li><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/separator.gif" alt="" /></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/admin/authentication?sa=logout"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/logout.png" alt="Logout" /></a></li><li><a href="http://docs.limesurvey.org"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/showhelp.png" alt="LimeSurvey online manual" /></a></li></ol></nav></div>
            <div id="content">
            <div class="acorn-page" >
    <nav class="menubar acorn-menu clearfix">
    
        <h1 class="acorn-plugin-title">Acorn Plugin</h1>
        
        <ol class="menubar-left level0"><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Cockpit"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons_040_stats.png" alt="Cockpit" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Texts"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons-547-quote.png" alt="Texts" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Rules"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons-69-ruler.png" alt="Rules" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Rulesets"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons-140-adjust-alt.png" alt="Rulesets" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Reports"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons-609-newspaper.png" alt="Reports" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=ReportTemplates"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons-37-file.png" alt="Report Templates" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=MaturityLevels"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons_323_calculator.png" alt="Maturity Levels" /></a></li><li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=Customers"><img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/plugins/AcornReporting/assets/images/glyphicons/glyphicons_043_group.png" alt="Customers" /></a></li></ol>        
        
    </nav>    
    <ul class="nav pull-right acorn-dropdown-menu" style="width:160px" id="yw0">
<li class="dropdown user"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i><span class="username">Development</span> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=UnitTest"><i class="icon-road"></i>Unit Test controller</a></li>
<li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=TestEM"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>EM in action</a></li>
<li><a href="/acorn/acorn-htm/index.php/plugins/direct?plugin=AcornReporting&amp;function=TestEM&amp;action=UnitTestEM"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>Unit Test EM</a></li>
<li><span></span></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Task</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>    

    
    <div class="container acorn-content">
            </div>
</div>

            </div>
            <div id="ajaxprogress" title="Ajax request in progress" style="text-align: center">
                <img src="/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen//images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='footer'>
    <div style='float:left;width:110px;text-align:left;'>
        <a href='http://manual.limesurvey.org'><img alt='LimeSurvey - Online manual' title='LimeSurvey - Online manual' src='/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/docs.png' /></a>
    </div>
    <div style='float:right;'>
        <a href='http://donate.limesurvey.org'><img alt='Support this project: Donate to LimeSurvey' title='Support this project: Donate to LimeSurvey!' src='/acorn/acorn-htm/styles/gringegreen/images/donate.png'/></a>
    </div>
    <div class='subtitle'><a class='subtitle' title='Visit our website!' href='http://www.limesurvey.org' target='_blank'>LimeSurvey</a><br />Version 2.05+ Build 150211</div>
</div>    <script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/7165e62e/js/notify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/acorn/acorn-htm/tmp/assets/5dcd5e76/js/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
jQuery('a[rel="popover"]').popover();
jQuery('#surveyid').select2({'minimumResultsForSearch':10,'placeholder':'Please choose...'});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Due to that, the dropdown list can not be updated.

**What went wrong and how do I fix this?**

Comment: What happens if you add "Yii:app()->end();" after the foreach()?

Comment: OOOOOH! That's it. Thank you very much. Perhaps someone can explain why this is needed?

Comment: I posted an answer with explanation as response with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the action code. This can be solved by ending the execution using exit() or more gracefully Yii:app()->end()

```
public function actionDynamicResponses() {
    $data = CHtml::listData(Response::model($_POST['survey_id'])->findAll(), 'id', 'id');

    foreach ($data as $value => $name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
    }

    // Gracefully end the action;
    Yii:app()->end();
}
```

Because you are relying on the normal exit of the controller, it's default action is to render the default page. By using exit() or Yii::app()->end(), you tell the action handler not to render the layout.

You can also achieve this by overwriting the layout in the controller;

```
$this->layout=false;
```

Comment: BTW, this is a bug in the limesurvey code, You should raise a bug request : https://www.limesurvey.org/en/community-services/bug-tracker (Actually reading again, this might be in your Acorn plugin - I'm not sure).

Comment: First, thank you very much for your help! :-)
Second, there are countless bugs in the plugin environment of limesurvey. The URL handling is the worst and caused some sleepless nights. As you can see in the view file there is no way to make use of Yii createURL method and so it has to be hardcoded.
Anyway I will check my controller again and eventually raise a bug request as you suggested. Thanks again.